# the underground stations

Tags: meaning-in-context

My texbook give next sentence:

> I take the underground **from** Kings Cross Station.

I have 2 questions:

1) Am I correct that I think we use **from** here because Kings Cross Station is the first staion of the underground line?

2) Can I say for stations which are not the first

> I take the underground **at** 'particular station'

when this **particular station** is not the first staion of the underground line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say *from* Kings Cross as it is the first station of your journey, not the first station of the line.  The expression relates to your journey.  Indeed, in that example, if you look at a London tube map you will see that Kings Cross is not at the start of any line.

The usage of *at* is more common in a phrase such as *you board a train at Kings Cross*.  Here the expression relates to the action of boarding the train rather than the journey.

Comment: One more question, please. In the sentense 'You can catch the bus from the top of the hill' - we use 'to catch' as the synonym of 'to take' (because of 'from')? And it means 'You can travel by bus from the top of the hill'?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find there clear explanation relating to this sentense. Could you help me, please. Or maybe I need to create new question about it?

Comment: @Selio In the example sentence in your other question, you're basically saying "There's a bus stop at the top of the hill, you can get on the bus there." And, yes, in that sense both "catch" and "take" have the same meaning.

Comment: Catch and take are interchangeable.  So, why do they feel a bit different to me?  I think it's this: catch has the connotation that buses are always trying to leave one behind (which as everyone knows they are) and therefore have to be caught.  Take doesn't have this connotation.  So, I'm going to say that the word "catch" conveys a *soupçon* of the shared feelings of anxiety, frustration, and resignation that bus travellers have all over the world, that is not conveyed by the matter-of-fact word "take".